# How to get RANCID to back up a Linksys SRW208?

Tags: rancid

I can write expect scripts to automate logins and backups on regular SSH prompts, but the SRW208 switch has a weird console GUI that makes it difficult to automate logging in. See picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XWIr.jpg

Are there any scripts out there that deal with this? If I can get past this screen and make it to the lcli prompt, I can get a backup, but I'm having trouble even logging in to these devices.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also send control characters via expect as far as i know , i used this method in pexpect , if after the initial telnet you can't send the user/pass.
You can send tab to get to the position , expect any character, and then send the user/pass.